# How to ignore Filters.in if no match values in an array

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query, mongodb-scala

I have the following aggregation pipeline:

```
  val sources = Seq("1.1.1.1", "6.6.6.6")
  val fileTypes = Seq("docx")

  val files = DB.fileRead.aggregate(Seq(
    Aggregates.filter(Filters.and(
      Filters.in("source", sources: _*),
      Filters.in("fileType", fileTypes: _*),
    ))
  ))
```

If the `sources` or `fileType` sequence is empty, how to construct a query to ignore its filter respectively such as, `Filters.in("source", sources: _*)` or `Filters.in("fileType", fileTypes: _*)`? I don't want to use `Filters.or()` since I want a result that produced by both filters in `Filters.and()`.